# Python "builtin_function_or_method" Error

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, concatenation

I have a problem writing files - I want to write in bytes, so I made a code:

```
read_file = open(data,"wb")#data is the path of the file
new_file.write(read_file.read)
read_file.close
```

It throws me this error

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' does not support the buffer interface
```

on the second line (`new_file.write(read_file.read)`)

Can somebody help me please?

Also, if I write some bytes to the file and then close it, and write bytes to the file again, they will concatenate. For example the if the first byte is `10101101` and the second byte is `10111101`, they will be read as `1010110110111101`?

Answer (score 0):

```
read_file= open(data,"wb")#data is the path of the file
new_file.write(read_file.read)
```

Should be

```
read_file= open(data,"rb")#data is the path of the file
new_file.write(read_file.read())
```

`read_file.read` is a function/method, you want to pass a string into `new_file.write()`. By invoking read `.read()` you will create a string inplace containing the contents of the file.

---

Regarding how the bytes would be written to a file, `.write("10101101")` will **not** append a newline character `"\n"` to the output. So all subsequent writes will appear along the same line of the file. To have them on a newline you can have `.write("10101101"+"\n")`

Comment: now it says thing on the corected line "io.UnsupportedOperation: read"

Comment: @AndrésOrtiz Sorry! Forgot to change the file opening parameter to `"rb"` for *read binary*. If you open a file in write mode `"w"` you can't read from it!